# how to make the jmeter sampler result to pass deliberately

Tags: jmeter

I've one simple jmeter login script for negative scenarios which takes invalid login and password.

It gives JSON response as 
    {
     "status": 401,
     "error": "unauthorised",
     }

The above response is expected.

I've also added the JSON Path Assertion to verify the status code as 401 which validates correctly

Now my target is if I run the test it should pass however its coming as fail status.
Sampler result shows as below

```
  Sample Count: 1
  Error Count: 1
```

How I can make it pass? Is it possible or not?

Comment: Is there any way we can call the org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.Sample and find getErrorCount() and make it to setErrorCount() as zero to make it pass status.

Comment: got the answer. Used the response assertion and checked the ignore status checkbox

Answer (score 0):

One more way is to add a BeanShell PostProcessor to that sample with `prev.setResponseOK();` 
This will pass the previous sample irrespective of whatever result it got.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add Response Assertion to your HTTP sampler and set check-box 'Ignore Status'. Then response will have status 403 and 'Error Count' equals to 0. Does it give result what you want?

Upd: Oops, author has already got the answer. Sorry